# Query to get last item in a column

Tags: sql

I have a table like this

| ID | TYPE |
| --- | --- |
| 12266 | XXL1L;XXL1L |
| 34153 | TOLT40ND;TOLT40ND |
| 63939 | TOLT40ND;TOLT40ND;POSTHT128 |
| 63940 | TOLT20ND;TOLT20ND |
| 90908 | TOLT40ND;TOLT40ND;POSTHT128 |
| 90909 | TOLT40ND;TOLT40ND;POSTHT128 |
| 59121 | TOLT30ND;TOLT30ND;MAR1639L;MAR1639L |
| 59131 | MAR1639L;MAR1639L |
| 152472 | TOLT30ND;TOLT30ND |

I only need the last Item in Type

This a result table

| ID | TYPE |
| --- | --- |
| 12266 | XXL1L |
| 34153 | TOLT40ND |
| 63939 | POSTHT128 |
| 63940 | TOLT20ND |
| 90908 | POSTHT128 |
| 90909 | POSTHT128 |
| 59121 | MAR1639L |
| 59131 | MAR1639L |
| 15247 | TOLT30ND |

Comment: Which database are you working with? Please add the relevant tag.

Comment: @HoneyBadger I think I prefer the result table to be fair

Answer (score 1):

This will change somewhat depending on what platform you are using but an idea that will work on all platforms is to do the following:  Reverse the string and find the location of the first `;` Then in the normal string take the right characters of that size.  So the function names change from platform to platform but something like this

```
  RIGHT(TYPE, STRPOS(REVERSE(TYPE),';'))
```

Note... aaron points out you may need to subtract one from the return of strpos to not include the ';' in the output.

Comment: I think you need a `-1` to not include the `;`

Comment: @AaronDietz -- yeah it depends on the platform -- in db2 you use -1 and in sql server you use reverse.   Probably use -1 in oracle too

Comment: Still need reverse, but charindex includes the `;` in the length... SQL Server way: `RIGHT(TYPE,CHARINDEX(';',REVERSE(TYPE))-1)`

Comment: oh I see what you mean -- yeah in db2 if you give a starting location as -1 it will start at the end of the string and go backwards.  That is what I thought you meant

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do in SQL Server:

```
WITH test AS
(
    SELECT  12266 ID,   'XXL1L;XXL1L' Type UNION all
    SELECT  34153 ,  'TOLT40ND;TOLT40ND' UNION all
    SELECT  63939 ,  'TOLT40ND;TOLT40ND;POSTHT128' UNION all
    SELECT  63940 ,  'TOLT20ND;TOLT20ND' UNION all
    SELECT  90908 ,  'TOLT40ND;TOLT40ND;POSTHT128' UNION all 
    SELECT  90909 ,  'TOLT40ND;TOLT40ND;POSTHT128' UNION all
    SELECT  59121 ,  'TOLT30ND;TOLT30ND;MAR1639L;MAR1639L' UNION all
    SELECT  59131 ,  'MAR1639L;MAR1639L' UNION all
    SELECT  152472,  'TOLT30ND;TOLT30ND' UNION ALL
    SELECT  123, 'TEST;;TEST'
)

SELECT  SUBSTRING(test.Type, LEN(test.Type) + 2 - CHARINDEX(';', REVERSE(test.Type)), LEN(test.Type)) 
FROM    test
```